# Two data bind attributes are not working in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using a function which is returning an integer value based on that I am looping it to generate html divs. Please see the below code:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: new Array(getCartTotalParam())">
     <div data-bind='text : $index()+1, css: { active: getCartParam("summary_count") >= $index()+1 }'></div>
</div>
```

the `getCartTotalParam()` is returning an integer let say 21, so I am generating 21 divs inside it.
Now I want to add a css class (as active).
The logic is I have used css binding which is call `getCartParam("summary_count")`. It checks the returned value and the loop's iteration index and based on this comparison I want to add css class.

But my code is not working. I have referred the doc but can't figure out what was missing.

Comment: Some general advice: you're putting way to much logic in your views. What does your viewmodel look like? Why isn't there an `observableArray` with a length you can use to create the `<div>`s? What do the elements represent?

Comment: getCartTotalParam() is returning 21 so I want to print 21 white bars and getCartParam("summary_count") is returning 8 so I want to highlight 8 bars among those 21 white bars. I didn't make any viewmodel yet. Its a hardcoded value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your code given above. There might be a mistake in your logic.

The `css` binding with the above-given (question) syntax would apply `active` css if the given expression `getCartParam("summary_count") >= $index()+1` is `true` otherwise it will not apply anything.

Here is working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qafire/edit?output)

Answer (score -1):

You should change your `$index()+1` as `($index()+1)` in your `<div>` tag like this,

```
<div data-bind='text : $index()+1, css: { active: getCartParam("summary_count") >= ($index()+1) }'></div>
```

Here is a working **DEMO** for you: http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5689/

Hope this helps!